# Assigning to variables using dynamic naming

Tags: matlab, dynamic, struct, naming-conventions

I am creating a function with two inputs, and would like to know how I can name the output accorinding to the name of the inputs.

E.g.

```
function  [padded_*input_name*] = padstruct(S, F)
```

later in code...

```
 else
    padded_*input_name* = padarray(toPad, (longest - size(toPad,1)), NaN('double'), 'post');
```

So if I enter a struct (labelled as `S` in the input arguments) called `my_struct`, I would like to get an output called `padded_my_struct`. But this should be free to change according to the name of the input struct. I want to do this because I have a lot of structs to run through this function and I want to explicitly know from the output name, which is which.

I am a beginner with Matlab and so would appreciate any exaplanation or references to literature.

Comment: Haha! padded_Boobies! Why didn't I think of a variable name like this before!

Comment: Anyone care to comment why I am gettng down-voted here? If there is a perfect answer already here somewhere, I can't find it. I saw related things, but were too complicated for me so I didn't know if they were solutions. Should I apologise for my ignorance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite give you what you want. Instead, I have a function that, given the inputs Account and F, produces in the base workspace a variable "padded_Account", and returns the name of the variable it creates.

```
function padded_Sname_str=padstruct(Sin,F)

%get the name of the structure used in the function call here
Sname=inputname(1);

%do stuff to Sin here
Sin.pad=F;  %this is just my test operation

%create the name of the new variable you want
padded_Sname_str=['padded_',Sname];

%this creates it in the base workspace, since passing back as an
%output argument doesn't preserve the name
assignin('base',padded_Sname_str,Sin)

return
```

Hope this is helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @Joe Serrano!  I will see if I can get this working in my code! I didn't come accross the function `assignin` in my searches - thanks again. I will post back with my solution... or next problem ;)

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept the answer if it was useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
function  [padded_*input_name*] = padstruct(S, F)

%// .. later on in code
else
    value = padarray(toPad, (longest - size(toPad,1)), NaN('double'), 'post');
    evalc(['padded_' inputname(1) '= value']);
```

Let us know if it works for you!